# how to change "Have a promotional code ?"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How do I change the "**Have a promotional code ?**" label in the woocommerce coupon?

I have tried including some php code which I found in the internet but it didn't work.

Please help me with this; I have also changed "**Have a promotional code?**" to "**Please enter your membership code below to apply discount**" in the form-coupon.php file.

code is below:

```
 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) {
    return;
}

if ( empty( WC()->cart->applied_coupons ) ) {
    $info_message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', __( 'Please enter your membership code in the coupon to apply discount', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 'Please enter your membership code below to apply discount', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' );
    wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );
}
?>

<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Member Code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

`

Thanks

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have used that is not working… thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](https://www.sellwithwp.com/rename-hide-coupon-code-field-woocommerce/) and follow the instructions. Or just paste the following code in your theme functions file:

```
function woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_cart( $translated_text, $text, $text_domain ) {
    // bail if not modifying frontend woocommerce text
    if ( is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $text_domain ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }
    if ( 'Apply Coupon' === $text ) {
        $translated_text = 'Put your text here';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_rename_coupon_field_on_cart', 10, 3 );
```

Then change 'put your text here'.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but the above code didn't work. I got my code from the link you have mentioned above.

Comment: In my cart page, I have enabled my coupon option, the coupon works fine but I actually want to change the label of the coupon which says "Have a Promotional Code?" to "Enter your member code"

Comment: if your site is running and up, send me the link. Also, you might apply css trick to hide it.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply, my site is not live, still in the development, I have even changed "Have a coupon?" to "Enter your member code" in the form-coupon.php file